# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError "certificate verify failed" when using Ruby Gem 'cryptsy-api'

Tags: ruby, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use the cryptsy-api gem, but seem to have some sort of SSL error. Here's the output in my irb session:

First I load the api:

```
$ irb
2.1.2 :001 > require 'cryptsy/api'
 => true
```

Then I set the two variables needed to make a connection (using fake names for this example)

```
2.1.2 :002 > key = 'thisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisa'
 => "thisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisa"
2.1.2 :003 > secret = 'thisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkey'
 => "thisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkey"
```

Now I instantiate a new instance:

```
2.1.2 :004 > cryptsy = Cryptsy::API::Client.new(key, secret)
 => #<Cryptsy::API::Client:0x007fcf6b81aff0 @key="thisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisa",     @secret="thisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkeythisisasecretkey", @private_caller=nil>
```

Here's where I get the error. When I call a method on the instance, it throws this error:

```
2.1.2 :005 > cryptsy.getinfo
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `block in connect'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:93:in `perform'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:521:in `perform_request'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/httparty-0.13.1/lib/httparty.rb:473:in `post'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cryptsy-api-0.1.4/lib/cryptsy/api.rb:36:in `execute_method'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cryptsy-api-0.1.4/lib/cryptsy/api.rb:204:in `call_private_api'
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cryptsy-api-0.1.4/lib/cryptsy/api.rb:82:in `getinfo'
  from (irb):5
  from /Users/caymanner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.2 :006 >
```

Any ideas why this happens? Am I forgetting to load some other gem?

Comment: oh. I thought I did ask it properly. I tried to make it more clear. Is this better?

Comment: My bad. I did not realize the network gear was implemented in the API. Did you see *"Maintenance - On going redesign of the cluster is resulting in login issues for a small but real portion of our user base"* from [Cryptsy API](http://www.cryptsy.com/pages/api) home page?

Comment: no problem :) I think I made the question more clear anyway :D

Comment: The maintenance message has cleared, and it's still not working. I have some similar code in PHP that works fine. I think it's Ruby-related. Thanks, though. One more step towards a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was at http://CascadiaRuby.com conference and talked with @thagomizer_rb who had been bitten by a bug like this a half dozen times. Apparently the OpenSSL libraries that ship with a Mac are out of date.

The fix was to install a more recent version of OpenSSL. My solution was to use brew:

$ brew update && brew install openssl